# Assembly.LoadFrom() or Assembly.Load() being able to delete file

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

My goal:
I am writing a vsix (Visual Studio extension) where i want to compile a project, then load the resulting .dll and inspect it via reflection. Due to how the code is written, i am unable to use `ReflectionOnlyLoad()`. If i simply do `Assembly.Load` then the file is locked until the user restarts the whole IDE.

I am trying to setup a separate AppDomain based on the samples i found online.

The gist of it is:
1. I created a Proxy class that would marshal the data across `AppDomain` instances:

```
internal class AppDomainProxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
        }
}
```

I then create an instance of it:

```
var domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, ShadowCopyDirectories = "true", ShadowCopyFiles = "true", LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost };

            var adevidence = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
            var domain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("reflection", adevidence, domaininfo);

             var proxyType = new AppDomainProxy().GetType();

            var proxyInstance = (AppDomainProxy)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(proxyType.Assembly.Location, proxyType.FullName);

            var loadedAssembly = (proxyInstance as AppDomainProxy).GetAssembly(this._assemblyLocation);
```

This fails to cast my transparent proxy to my `AppDomainProxy` type.
To workaround this, one can easily supply an assembly resolver like so:

```
            this.domain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;

private Assembly CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            var loadedAssemblies = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            foreach (var assembly in loadedAssemblies)
            {
                if (assembly.FullName == args.Name)
                {
                    return assembly;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

This works fine, my proxy is cast.
However, when i call my method, the `CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve` is invoked again, suggesting to me that `Assembly` property is not really serializable and so .net is simply trying to load the Assembly on the original side, thus resulting in the same problem as `Assembly.Load`. This is easy to see because simple Microsoft samples like `return AppDomain.Current.FriendlyName;` work just fine.

**UPDATE** As a workaround, i just moved my code that needed the Assembly to run on the other side (inside the domain) and then return the string back which marshals fine. I will keep the question open, though, because i want to know if there is a solution for the actual issue.

Comment: Well you're back at square one again because the assembly is now loaded in _both_ AppDomains and you can only `Unload()` one of them.  Why not do everything that needs to be done in your secondary AppDomain?

Comment: @MickyD As per the update to the question, this is what i ended up doing. But i don't like it :/

Comment: Don't like it?   That's the whole point of AppDomains.  Creating an Appdomain for isolation to load say an assembly or plugin only to return it to the parent domain defeats the purpose of sandboxes in exactly the same way if you created a child thread to perform a lengthy task but only to block wait for it to complete.  There are some good articles I suggest you read on MSDN Magazine re app domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course you need to move the code that needs to work with the assembly to the separate `AppDomain`. There's no magic involved - if you need to work with a type from a referenced assembly, you need to load that assembly.

There's two main ways of marshalling objects across `AppDomain` boundaries (and other remoting scenarios): either you make a copy of the object, or you marshal all the method calls. Both are very tricky - you must make sure you never leak the types that are in the referenced assembly, otherwise you need to load it into *both* domains. In your case, you can't marshal the method calls because `Assembly` is *not* (and cannot be) a `MarshalByRefObject` - your proxy must return a real `Assembly` object, and cannot create the marshalling proxy.

To get proper isolation, you must avoid leaking any types from assemblies you don't want to share, as well as non-marshallable types that may expose any of those. This usually means sticking to primitives and types from a shared library if you can afford that. Keep a nice tight interface, and try not to exploit the "automatic" marshalling too much - returning an automatic proxy to a complex object is convenient, but makes it much harder to understand the scope of the interface. Does the object have a method that returns a type from the non-shared assembly? Too bad, you need to load it in your domain as well.

In general, working with multiple AppDomains that actually interoperate (and the related .NET remoting) is a huge pain. It's complex, prone to errors and rather hard to get right. You can read whole books on the subject. There's a reason why using them is no longer recommended - and why they aren't supported in PCLs (and for a long time, haven't been supported in Mono). Are they still useful? Yeah. Software isolation has very nice benefits. But you need to be really careful not to mess things up :)

Comment: _"It's complex, prone to errors and rather hard to get right. You can read whole books on the subject"_ - perhaps.  You could say the same thing about encryption;  claims-based security; VS language services, and visual recognition.  Doesn't mean we shouldn't give up just because of a few poorly written books.  As for AD, I found some brilliant MSDN mag circa 2006 articles that helped me greatly

Comment: @MickyD Yup, I'm not saying you shouldn't use it. I'm saying you need to learn a lot, and make sure you're doing it right. You'll find that for a lot of cases where you'd call on app domains, you can actually find a better solution. And ideally, avoid being exposed to them directly - an ASP.NET programmer almost never needs to think about app domains, even though they're very important to ASP.NET programs. Just like you wouldn't write your own encryption algorithm - you use the highest abstraction available that actually solves your problem.

Comment: I will accept it because beside the philosophical point, the answer is correct - `Assembly` is not `MarshalByRefObject` and is thus loaded in both App domains. To work around this, i did all the work in the child app domain.